# jQuery jPicker path issues when used in WordPress Theme Options

Tags: jquery

Anyone with experience using jPicker colorpicker in a WordPress Custom Theme options panel. I believe that the default path for the jPicker resources is /jPicker/ relative to the location the js file appears, however, I'm not seeing the picker.gif icon, so I tried changing the path in the js file like so...

```
images:{clientPath:"../wp-content/themes/myTheme/images/"
```

Everything else appears to be working at first load. My bound input field's background color is the same as the currently selected color. However, the picker.gif icon is missing. Where it should appear, I've just got a 2px wide by 20px tall color element (looks like a div perhaps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute path instead of relative. So if your image is under `.../wp-content/themes/myTheme/images/myGif.gif` location use this: `images:{clientPath:"/wp-content/themes/myTheme/images/"`